# I found an apple IIe without a power supply where can i find one

Tags: hardware, apple-ii

I found an apple IIe without a power supply where can i find one also any tips on where i can find other parts for it. Btw i know nothing about Retrocomputers.

Answer (score 2):

The Apple IIe power supply specifications can be found at [this link](http://www.applelogic.org/files/AIIETECHREF3.pdf).

The specifications are:

[image]

And the connector pinout is:

[image]

I can't tell if you are trying to repair an existing power supply brick (if so there are web sites and Youtube links for that) or if you are willing to replace it with something else that meets or exceeds the requirements for the Apple IIe.

But if you are willing to simply find an equivalent power supply that gets you to the right place, and you are willing to adapt such a power supply to the connector you have in hand (cut and paste work, perhaps), then the above specifications should be sufficient. (I have three supplies that meet those specs and I paid exactly US$2 for each one at a shop in the San Francisco area, some years back, when I was visiting.)

Regardless, the above information is all you need to either find someone to help you or else find a power supply that will meet your needs.

You could also consider paying someone to repair your existing power supply. These old supplies are not rocket science. So you should be able to find someone able to achieve that much for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by "I found an Apple //e". Are you assuming it is a working machine, just in need of a missing PSU?

The best option would be to obtain a known good/working Apple PSU for it. Better yet, an entire working Apple //e would provide a source of swappable parts that you can use to troubleshoot a non-working machine, which is what you may have now.

Without getting into a quagmire of troubleshooting it yourself, you could likely sell it to another collector who has the troubleshooting tools/parts needed to get it working.

If you prefer to tackle the project yourself, I'd recommend one of:

1. Go online and locate a working Apple II PSU offered by a reputable seller. Beware this may fix the missing PSU but then you have other potential faults to contend with (If luck does not favor you).
2. Build a bench-top power supply that you can use to power up the motherboard and see if it is working. This will give you confidence to shell out for the working PSU you need.

Answer (score 1):

ReActive Micro sell new PSUs. The other alternatives if you can source cables is a Q-60B psu from one of the AliExpress vendors, you'll need 12V,-12V,5V and -5V

An original PSU will almost certainly need the RIFA capacitors fixing.

Answer (score 0):

My Apple II runs fine with an old PC PSU (though this one still had -5V). So you do not need an original one.

Comment: Modern PC PSUs still have -12V. What they miss is -5V but this is easily derived from -12V.